# User gradient as active color in Switch flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to generate this switch with the Switch widget?

[image: toggle]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [custom_switch](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_switch) package. I changed it for linearGradient.

```
library custom_switch;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color inactiveColor;
  final String activeText;
  final String inactiveText;
  final Color activeTextColor;
  final Color inactiveTextColor;

  const CustomSwitch(
      {Key key,
      this.value,
      this.onChanged,
      this.activeColor,
      this.inactiveColor = Colors.grey,
      this.activeText = '',
      this.inactiveText = '',
      this.activeTextColor = Colors.white70,
      this.inactiveTextColor = Colors.white70})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomSwitchState createState() => _CustomSwitchState();
}

class _CustomSwitchState extends State<CustomSwitch>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation _circleAnimation;
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 60));
    _circleAnimation = AlignmentTween(
            begin: widget.value ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: widget.value ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.linear));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if (_animationController.isCompleted) {
              _animationController.reverse();
            } else {
              _animationController.forward();
            }
            widget.value == false
                ? widget.onChanged(true)
                : widget.onChanged(false);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 70.0,
            height: 35.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              // I commented here.
              // color: _circleAnimation.value == Alignment.centerLeft
              //     ? widget.inactiveColor
              //     : widget.activeColor,

              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                // You can set your own colors in here!
                colors: [
                  Colors.blue,
                  Colors.red,
                ],
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0, right: 4.0, left: 4.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _circleAnimation.value == Alignment.centerRight
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 34.0, right: 0),
                          child: Text(
                            widget.activeText,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: widget.activeTextColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container(),
                  Align(
                    alignment: _circleAnimation.value,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 25.0,
                      height: 25.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  _circleAnimation.value == Alignment.centerLeft
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 34.0),
                          child: Text(
                            widget.inactiveText,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: widget.inactiveTextColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is main.dart:

```
import 'package:custom_switch/custom_switch.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  bool status = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Custom Switch Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomSwitch(
              activeColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
              value: status,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print("VALUE : $value");
                setState(() {
                  status = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
            Text('Value : $status', style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20.0
            ),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]