# How to add gradient to my standard switch in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, size, gradient

How can I change my standard Switch

[image]

to this gradient switch

[image]

Also how to increase the size of switch?
Please help.

Code:-

```
                    Switch(
                  activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                  inactiveThumbColor: Colors.grey,
                  value: _switchValueRead,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _switchValueRead = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by this from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353767/user-gradient-as-active-color-in-switch-flutter)

```
library custom_switch;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
  final Color activeColor;
  final Color inactiveColor;
  final String activeText;
  final String inactiveText;
  final Color activeTextColor;
  final Color inactiveTextColor;

  const CustomSwitch(
      {Key key,
      this.value,
      this.onChanged,
      this.activeColor,
      this.inactiveColor = Colors.grey,
      this.activeText = '',
      this.inactiveText = '',
      this.activeTextColor = Colors.white70,
      this.inactiveTextColor = Colors.white70})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomSwitchState createState() => _CustomSwitchState();
}

class _CustomSwitchState extends State<CustomSwitch>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation _circleAnimation;
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 60));
    _circleAnimation = AlignmentTween(
            begin: widget.value ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: widget.value ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.linear));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if (_animationController.isCompleted) {
              _animationController.reverse();
            } else {
              _animationController.forward();
            }
            widget.value == false
                ? widget.onChanged(true)
                : widget.onChanged(false);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 70.0,
            height: 35.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              // I commented here.
              // color: _circleAnimation.value == Alignment.centerLeft
              //     ? widget.inactiveColor
              //     : widget.activeColor,

              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                // You can set your own colors in here!
                colors: [
                  Colors.blue,
                  Colors.red,
                ],
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0, right: 4.0, left: 4.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _circleAnimation.value == Alignment.centerRight
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 34.0, right: 0),
                          child: Text(
                            widget.activeText,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: widget.activeTextColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container(),
                  Align(
                    alignment: _circleAnimation.value,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 25.0,
                      height: 25.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  _circleAnimation.value == Alignment.centerLeft
                      ? Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 34.0),
                          child: Text(
                            widget.inactiveText,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: widget.inactiveTextColor,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked with the gradient, but I want a standard switch not the cupertino switch so how can I do that?
Also InactiveColor is not getting overridden so how to change Inactive Color of the Switch?

Answer (score 0):

[Check this for gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64355302/13198893)

For increasing the size - wrap your Switch into Container (or SizedBox) and set width and height to Container(SizedBox). It should help.